# Align Images Side By Side with hover

Tags: html, css

```
<div align="center">
<div class="container2">
      <a href="D:/Games/CIC/MFWS/discussion.html"><img src="img/3.png" alt="discussion Threads" class="image" height="200px" width="150px"></a>
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Here you can discuss different topics and ask or answer questions.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
        <img src="download.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay overlay2">
            <div class="text">Bottom</div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
    <img src="download.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay overlay3">
        <div class="text">Bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

i want to make the images next to each other but i can't idk why or how tbh and this is the css i have tried everything it doesn't work
I want 3 images side by side with hover and caption, at the moment I have 3 images going from top to bottom, the hover is good but not side by side. How do I make the images appear side by side? Thanks.

```
.container2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 17%;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border-top-left-radius: 70px;
  border-top-right-radius: 70px;
  pointer-events: none
}

.container2:hover .overlay {
  height: 85%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
.overlay2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border-top-left-radius: 70px;
  border-top-right-radius: 70px;
  pointer-events: none
}
.container2:hover .overlay2 {
  height: 85%;
}
.overlay3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border-top-left-radius: 70px;
  border-top-right-radius: 70px;
  pointer-events: none
}
.container2:hover .overlay3 {
  height: 85%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add `float` property to your `container2` selector. Please check the css rule below.

```
.container2 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" style="background-color:red">

  </div>
  <div class="item" style="background-color:blue">

  </div>
  <div class="item" style="background-color:yellow">

  </div>
</div>
```

Why don't you grid-display property ?

[This might help you](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Answer (score 0):

For these such scenarios there is a beautiful/clean/simple concept called `flex` which is helping by decreasing number of lines of code:

here is the example with `column`, `color` and `hover` effect, hope it helps you:

```css
#MainDiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 650px;
  display: flex;
  /* here is a concept */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* you can either change it to row/columns */
  padding: 5px;
}

#firstDiv {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

#secondDiv {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#thirdDiv {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}

#firstDiv:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#secondDiv:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

#thirdDiv:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainDiv">
  <div id="firstDiv">First Div</div>
  <div id="secondDiv">Second Div</div>
  <div id="thirdDiv">Third Div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mahmoud Samy, is this what you need?